# Matlab median(A(:,:,I), 3)

Tags: matlab

[image]

[image]

I have matrix A and I. When I run

> Z = median(A(:,:,I), 3)

It gives me this output but I do not know how.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a look at your code

```
Z = median(A(:,:,I), 3)
```

What this says is that you want to find the median of some 3D matrix along the 3rd dimension.

Note that `I=[0 1 1]` means that `A(:,:,I)` selects the 2nd and 3rd pages of matrix `A`. When we call `median(A(:,:,I), 3)` we are asking for the median then across only pages 2 and 3 which results in an average of pages 2 and 3 because the median of two items is equal to the mean.